Unhandled Runtime Error Invariant Violation: An error occurred
I am getting an error when using the following code in Next.js and graphql project. I am not able to figure out.This is a component called 'UserComponent". Using Next.js page router and call this component from Home() in Page.tsx . I am trying to use the endpoint of the api , that I have in the apollo server. Pointing the error to
 *const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(dataListQuery);

**Page.tsx**

export default async function Home() {
 
  return (
        <div>
      <UserComponent/>      
    </div>
     );} 
         
**UserComponent.tsx**                                     ^*

const dataListQuery = gql`
  query {   
    id 
    name 
    email
  }
`;  

  function UserComponent(){
   const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(dataListQuery);
  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error: {error.message}</p>;
  const { user } = data;

  return (  
    <ApolloProvider client={client}> 
    <div>
      <p>  {user.name} </p>
    </div>
    </ApolloProvider> 
  );
};

export default UserComponent;

Unhandled Runtime Error
Invariant Violation: An error occurred! For more details, see the full error text at https://go.apollo.dev/c/err#%7B%22version%22%3A%223.9.10%22%2C%22message%22%3A49%2C%22args%22%3A%5B%5D%7D

What is the error message? You cut it off just where it gets interesting.

added the full error above

If you click on that link, it will tell you that the error is "Could not find "client" in the context or passed in as an option. Wrap the root component in an , or pass an ApolloClient instance in via options."
Do you have an ApolloProvider in your application?

Yes, I have been trying with ApolloProvider. The code above shows , I have used in the UserComponent. @phry

The provider needs to wrap around the component using useQuery. In your case, it wraps the children of UserComponent, but doesn't allow for useQuery inside of UserComponent itself. It needs to be in Home, or your App.

As i am using Next.js 14 and it says to use getclient installing experimental-nextjs-app-support/rsc . Is that right?

You say you are using the pages router, that package is for the app router.

this says can use for page router https://www.apollographql.com/blog/how-to-use-apollo-client-with-next-js-13 ?

That blog post is about React Server Components which are only available in the App router.
Please trust me, I'm the maintainer of that package, it's not meant for the pages router.

See this example of a setup for the pages router: https://github.com/apollographql/next-apollo-example/tree/main/pages
